# Getting root node attribute, jQuery/XML

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, response

this is probably so trivial that I'm ashamed to be asking this...

Why in the world is this not working?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<filter id="4" max_values="10">
    <value id="9">strategy</value>
    <value id="11">simulation</value>
    <value id="12">shooter</value>
</filter>
```

This is the xml response I get when I request the page with:

```
$.post('afilters/getvaluesXml', {filter_id: fid}, 
            function(response){
                var fields;
                alert(response);

                var filter_id = $(response).find('filter').attr('id');
                var max_values = parseInt($(response).find('filter').attr('max_values'));

                alert('filter_id: '+filter_id+' max_values:'+max_values);

                $(response).find('value').each(function(){
                    var id = $(this).attr('id');
                    var value = $(this).text();

                    if(max_values == 1){
                        fields = fields+'<input type="radio" name="'+filter_id+'" value="'+id+'"/>'+value+'<br/>';
                    } else {
                        fields = fields+'<input type="checkbox" name="'+filter_id+'[]" value="'+id+'"/>'+value+'<br/>';
                    }

                });
                //alert(fields);
                $('#'+filter_id+'_values').text(fields);
            });
```

Everything works fine except I am unable to get the filter_id and max_values attributes.
This is the alert box content:

filter_id: null max_values:NaN

And, why when I specify the datatype "xml" as described in the [jquery .post() docu](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), nothing gets back to me (no response is ever received - callback is never executed).

Comment: not working when setting datatype to `xml` is weird, because I got it working that way and RafH got it working this way too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Damn... Well you are all right. It is just me who forgot to set the proper header before outputting the xml...

So setting the output header to "content-type: text/xml" entirely fixed this problem.

Seems jQuery won't execute the callback when the content type is not as expected.

It is however weird that everything apart those two root node attributes worked :)

Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: consider accepting an answer, or at least show us a little gratidute and vote up :)

Comment: I voted up your posts. However the headers were the problem so for the sake of someone trying to identify the solution, I should mark my own answer as the "correct answer" though I don't want any attribution for it :)

Comment: If none of our answers are correct, and you worked it out, then why not mark your answer? :)

Comment: Omer, Juraj, I had this same problem and it's not easy to identify, took a few searches to get here.  Your combined work got me through, thanks to you both.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried setting **dataType to xml and it worked** like a charm, have a look at this snippet:

```
$.post('afilters/getvaluesXml', {filter_id: fid}, function(response){
  var filter_id = $('filter', response).attr('id');
  var max_values = parseInt($('filter', response).attr('max_values'));
  alert('filter_id: '+filter_id+' max_values:'+max_values);
 }, 'xml');
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the best practice but it works

```
var filter_id = $(response).find("value:first").parent().attr('id');
var max_values = $(response).find("value:first").parent().attr('max_values');
```